# How to create FPDF tables?

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a problem creating tables with fpdf.

Can anyone help me making this page (or at least tell me how to do it)?

- [invoice tables](http://puertoricohoops.net/invoicestimate/pdf/template.html)

*Or can you show how to convert* HTML tables to FPDF tables and put the code here?

I also have this (along with the connection to the database):

```
$person = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

I would like this to function when added inside the tables with this = (example)

```
$pdf->Cell(0,260,''.$person["CA"],'C',0 ,1); --- .$person["CA"]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the specific problem you have?

Comment: i just cant seem to make the tables... like for example if I follow the tutorial provided by fpdf they show text extracted from  countries.txt... but I want to extract the text from $_POST function..i have this http://puertoricohoops.net/invoicestimate/pdf/pdf8.php - and the text inside the tables is extracted from a .txt file, but I want those spots filled with my $_POST function.. thnx for helping

Answer (score 6):

Well, FPDF works kinda like a typewriter, in that it has a roving X,Y point which it writes to, which you can manually move around or let it do it for you.

I don't know if the huge whitespace at the left is required.  If so, you'd have to call $this->SetX($coordinate) before each write.

You should do something like this:

```
class InvoicePDF extends FPDF //Create a new class to contain the header/footer/etc. which extends FPDF
{
    public function Header()
    {
    //Header stuff goes here, like the big Invoice
        $this->SetY(10); //SetY 10 units down from the top, experiment with distance to get appropriate distance
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',20); //Set Font to Arial/Helvetica 20 pt font
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0); //Set Text Color to Black;
        $this->Cell(0,9,"INVOICE",0,0,'R');  //Write the word INVOICE Right aligned in a box the width of the page, will put it at the far right of the page
     }

     public function Footer()
     {
       //any footer stuff goes here
     }
     
     public function FillHeadInfo($info) //$info would be an array of the stuff to fill the small table at the top
     {
          $this->SetY(0); //reset the Y to the original, since we moved it down to write INVOICE
          $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
          $this->SetFillColor(224,224,224); //Set background of the cell to be that grey color
          $this->Cell(20,12,"Order #",1,0,'C',true);  //Write a cell 20 wide, 12 high, filled and bordered, with Order # centered inside, last argument 'true' tells it to fill the cell with the color specified
          $this->Cell(20,12,"Coding",1,0,'C',true);
          $this->Cell(20,12,"Sales Code",1,1,'C',true); //the 1 before the 'C' instead of 0 in previous lines tells it to move down by the height of the cell after writing this
          
          $this->Cell(20,12,$info['ordernum'],1,0,'C');
          $this->Cell(20,12,$info['coding'],1,0,'C');
          $this->Cell(20,12,$info['salescode'],1,1,'C');
          
          $this->Cell(40,12,"Name & Address",1,0,'C',true);
          $this->Cell(20,12,"Date",1,1,'C',true);
          $y = $this->GetY(); //Need the current Y value to reset it after the next line, as multicell automatically moves down after write
          $x = $this->GetX(); // Might need the X too
          $this->MultiCell(40,12,$info['customername'] . "\n" . $info['address'] . "\n" . $info['city'] . ', ' . $info['state'] . ' ' . $info['zip'],1,'L',false); //I assume the customer address info is broken up into multiple different pieces
          $this->SetY($y);  //Reset the write point
          $this->SetX($x + 40); //Move X to $x + width of last cell

          $this->Cell(20,36,date("format",strtotime($info['date'])),1,1,'C');  //Might be easier to use $this->Rect() to draw rectangles for address and date and then write the address and date into them without borders using SetX and SetY, if the borders don't line up or whatever

     }

     public function fillItems($items)
     {
          //You'd build the items list much the same way as above, using a foreach loop or whatever
          //Could also easily combine this function and the one above
     }
}
```

Then, when creating the pdf you'd do something like this:

```
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('class.invoicepdf.php');
//Get whatever info you need to fill the pdf
$pdf = new InvoicePDF('P','mm','Letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->FillHeadInfo($info);  //Could also pass $_POST and rely on the keys of the $_POST array
$pdf->FillItems($items);
$pdf->Output('filename.pdf','I');
```

By the way, I'd suggest rather than trying to write it from $_POST, you save the order to the DB, then pass the order ID along to the script to write the pdf via a link and $_GET, and have the script retrieve the info from the DB, this way you can select only the info you need.

Comment: thnx for responding.  did you try the code ? php gives this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting '(' (below  public function Header)       -- also I dont understand the build items list, I say, in my case, .$person["CA"] = address ??

Comment: it gives this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR .. on the lines were this is: $y = this->GetY(0); and $x = this->GetX(0);.. if I eliminate them I get this distortioned: http://puertoricohoops.net/invoicestimate/pdf/pdf9.php - if you could provide an example of your code in a link it would be nice.. thanx!

Comment: were do i get this info from -----   $info['ordernum']  is ordernum y $_POST name="" value?

Comment: Oh, oops, forgot the () after the header and footer function declarations.  class.invoicepdf.php would just be the file that contains the InvoicePDF class code.  Also, that should be $y = $this->GetY() and $x = $this->GetX(), note no 0s in them either.  'ordernum' could be a $_POST input field name or it could be the name of the column in an associatively fetched MySQL row, or it could be completely arbitrary key in a pieced together array from any source.

Comment: @Phoenix: Cell function do not wrap the contents of cell, if content length exceeds the width of cell the it flow away. Ugly affect if u have address and show using cell, then it will run away from page. did you know how t fix this?

Comment: I got a great Idea from you for using the link with ID thanks